# Записи в Delphi и StringGrid

Tags: delphi

Вопрос по Delphi. Мне необходимо создать запись, ввести данные и их отобразить в StringGrid. Но данные-то в edit записываются не один раз, а переписать их нужно в разные ячейки StringGrid. Подскажите, с помощью чего можно это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

А есть ещё такой способ: позволяет записать данные из Edit в любую ячейку StringGrid - выделяем ячейку, пишем данные в Edit, выделяем другую ячейку и снова пишем.

Технология:
Объявим глобальные переменные:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Col, Row: Integer; // номера строки и столбца
```

Создаем обработчик для StringGrid на событие OnSelectCell:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; var CanSelect: Boolean);
begin
// lebel стоит для удобства, чтобы знать какая ячейка выделена
  Label1.Caption:='выделена ячейка: '+IntToStr(ACol)+' ; '+IntToStr(ARow);
  Edit1.Clear; // очищаем на всякий случай Edit
  Col:=ACol; // сохраняем столбец
  Row:=ARow; // сохраняем строку
end;
```

Создаём обработчик события OnChange для Edit:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (Edit1.Text<>'') Then // если поле не пустое, пишем текст в ячейку сетки
    StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row]:=Edit1.Text;
end;
```

Ну, и на всякий пожарный создадим обработчик для кнопки:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row]:=Edit1.Text;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

А что мешает каждый раз менять номер строки и столбца для записи значения из Edit?

```
    var
       i,j : integer;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     i:=0;
     j:=0;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var zapis : string;
    begin
    zapis := Edit1.Text;
 if(i<=StringGrid1.ColCount-1)
 begin
  if(j<=StringGrid1.RowCount-1)
   begin
     i:=i+1;//collums
     j:=j+1;//rows
     StringGrid1.Cells[i,j]:= zapis;    
   end
  else MessageDlg('Кончились строки!', mtInformation,[mbOk],0);
 end
  else MessageDlg('Кончились столбцы!', mtInformation,[mbOk],0);    
end;
```

так значения будут записаны в StringGrid по диагонали.

Comment: Вылетит с ошибкой когда переменные выдут за colCounter или RowCounter

Comment: Ну естественно) Я думаю, что Екатерина Самойлова уже столкнулась с этой проблемой, а если нет то, я подправил ответ)

Comment: Судя потому что задаются вопросы такого плана то вряд ли человек имеет опыт работы с StringGrid1

Я бы сделал так:
    StringGrid1.RowCount:=J+1;
    StringGrid1.ColCount:=I+1;
тогда таблица сама себя будет наращивать
И если задатся целью писать по диагонали то достаточно 1 переменной :)

Вот [статейка](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/stringgrid.php) по работе c  StringGrid

Answer (score 0):

Иной раз "лучше поздно, чем никогда".
Здесь тоже есть ряд функций (в рамках темы):

https://roamer55.ru/main_programming/delphi/delphi_10_2_vcl/d10_funcs_tstringgrid/

Может тоже будет полезен.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)