# Перенос сведений из полей в ячейки таблицы

Tags: delphi

Как сделать перенос общих сведений, вводимых в заполняемые поля, в нужные ячейки таблицы?
И подсчитать количество вхождений символа «&» в текстовую таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятна первая часть вопроса: если таблица TStringGrid, то у него в свойстве Options есть настройка goEditing, её нужно поставить True, и в сетку можно вводить данные с клавиатуры.

Вторая часть:

1. Заводим переменные: кол-во символов, счётчик строк, счётчик столбцов, длина строки, индекс элемента строки (все переменные целые);
2. кол-во символов = 0;
3. Мотаем цикл от 0 до кол-во строк-1;
4. Мотаем цикл от 0 до кол-во столбцов-1;
5. Берём из ячейки строку;
6. Присваиваем её длину переменной;
7. Затем мотаем цикл от 1 до длины строки;
8. Если символ = "&", то кол-во символов = кол-во символов + 1.
9. Выводим результат.

Вот как-то так.

Первая часть задания: можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29830/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-delphi-%D0%B8-stringgrid?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=36315#36315), если, конечно, это поможет.

Comment: Дую так понятнее будет стаж оклад  
                      50000   1
При нажатии кнопки поменялось на вот так : стаж оклад
                                            1   50000